# Azure stateful service - Swagger not working with Kestrel when using UseUniqueServiceUrl

Tags: c#, .net, azure, swagger

In my program.cs im using Kestrel with **ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl**

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    var codePackageActivationContext = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext();
    var environment = new FabricConfigurationLoader(codePackageActivationContext).Get("Conf", "Environment");

    return new[]
    {
        new ServiceReplicaListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, (url, listener) =>
                new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseEnvironment(environment)
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .ConfigureServices(
                        services => services
                            .AddSingleton<StatefulServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                            .AddSingleton<IReliableStateManager>(this.StateManager))
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl)
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build()))
    };
}
```

This creates unique url for my service for example:

`localhost:53770/f740151b-43eb-455f-8759-e158e4934eb9/131432790864330387/66119e4b-4973-47cf-8471-0bd084a27abe`

Now, when I add `/swagger/ui` to the end of this url whe swagger does not work:

[browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qps0L.png)

I get the following error:

`the swagger.json file does exist in localhost:53770/f740151b-43eb-455f-8759-e158e4934eb9/131432790864330387/66119e4b-4973-47cf-8471-0bd084a27abe/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

, but the UI is not working!

Please advise

Comment: Were you able to figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try specifying SwaggerEndpoint as relative.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "your service name V1");
            });
```

Also, need to set RouteTemplate

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            });
```

Comment: Nope, that did not help